# using jQuery ajax method in cakePHP, return id of newly saved data to ajax onSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Im using cakePHP 2.2.1

I have a **GoalsController** that has an **add** action in it. This action saves posted data to Goals table.

Inside the **add.ctp** im using jQuery ajax method to post the form data to above said **add** action.

What i want is,

1. ajax method posts form data to goals/add
2. goals/add action saves data to goals table
3. Obtain the id of newly inserted row using $this->Goal->id
4. Return this id back to the onSuccess function of ajax method

Steps 1,2,3 are working fine. But i dont know how to implement step4.

I know php is server side and js is client side and all. Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to read the book entry on [Json views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) and implement something like this:

```
// Routes.php
Router::parseExtensions('json');

// Controller
$this->set('id', $this->Goal->id);
$this->set('_serialize', array('id'));

// AppController.php
public $components = array('RequestHandler'); // Or add 'RequestHandler' to the existing list.
```

Then you need to make your ajax post to `/goals/add.json`, Cake will then recognise the `.json` extension in combination with the `$this->set('_serialize')` and return a json string along the lines of `{ id: 1 }`.

Then in your `$.ajax` function, have a success call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/goals/add.json',
    dataType: 'json'
    // other settings
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.id); // response contains the returned data
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer is fine, but don't forget you need to add RequestHandler to your components list

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Thanks for the reply. I tried what you advised. But im getting 500 Internal error in Firebug console. 
This is the resonse:

Comment: Ah you'll need to make a view file for your action, just an `add.ctp` in the normal location. Not ideal as you'll never use it (could use it as a non-javascript fallback)

Comment: @José Lorenzo do i need to create an extra file named **add.json** for this method to work? I currently have put the form elements and ajax code in the **add.ctp** file.

Comment: Sorry you are right, the strange thing is it's looking for a json view file which I thought it would skip doing as you're using `$this->set('_serialize', array('id'));`. Try making a `View/Goals/json/add.ctp` and `echo json_encode(compact('id'));` inside it

Comment: No you don't if you use the special _serialize variable with set(), just make sure you are using CakePHP 2.1+

Comment: Read this to know how it works: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html